# Logging enabled and multilingual functionality?

Tags: core, logging, multilingual

After [Missing view when logging set in a non-US English instance.](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1812)
, I wonder if anyone has investigated the effects of turning a site from multilingual to monolingual or vice-versa whilst logging was enabled?  I have been working on a patch to solve the issue, and found some 'interesting' effects.